# Keypress not registering in access subform after subform sourceobject update

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, keypress, subform

In access, after changing a subform sourceobject via vba, keypress events do not fire. 
I've done this successfully multiple times before where the souceobject doesn't change.

KeyPreview is on in both the subform and form. 
If I delete the subform, the events trigger correctly.
I've been unable to find any resources online which describe this issue, and to me it appears to be a bug in access, but if someone has a magical fix, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.